# Save email to a folder if subject line matches

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to save an email, when it arrives, into a folder if the subject line contains the right term.

This code would end up being copied for 75-80 items all with varying subject lines.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub InboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal objItem As Object)
    Dim msgNew As MailItem
    Dim DateYr As Object
    Dim DateMonth As Object

    If objItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set msgNew = objItem
        If (msgNew.Subject Like "Client Media Report*") Then
            DateYr = Format(Now(), "yyyy", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem)
            DateMonth = Format(Now(), "mm. mmmm", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem)

            On Error Resume Next
            MkDir "M:\AutoArchive\Client Media Report\" & DateYr
            On Error GoTo 0
            msgNew.SaveAs "M:\AutoArchive\Client Media Report\" & DateYr & "\" & DateMonth & ".msg"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I'd expect this to save a new email into the correct folder. E.g., the example would save into `M:\AutoArchive\Client Media Report\2019\08. August`

It doesn't save and doesn't spit an error.

Example subject line: `Client Media Report 05 August 2019`

Example file location:  `M:\AutoArchive\Client Media Report\2019\08. August`

EDIT: Updated with latest code, event triggers error

> Unable to open item

on

```
Set mai = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strEntryId)
```

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    MsgBox ("Test1")

    Dim mai As Object
    Dim msgNew As MailItem
    Dim DateYr As Object
    Dim DateMonth As Object

    Set mai = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strEntryId)
    MsgBox mai.Subject

    If mai.Class = olMail Then
    Set msgNew = objItem
        If (msgNew.Subject Like "DPS Front Pages*") Then
            DateYr = Format(Now(), "yyyy", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem)
            DateMonth = Format(Now(), "mm. mmmm", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem)

            On Error Resume Next
            MkDir "D:\AutoArchive\Full Front Pages\" & DateYr
            On Error GoTo 0
            msgNew.SaveAs "D:\AutoArchive\Full Front Pages\" & DateYr & "\" & DateMonth & msgNew.Subject & ".msg"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event of the Application class which is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox.

The NewMailEx event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance. However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously.

```
Private Sub NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    Dim mai As Object
    Dim msgNew As MailItem
    Dim DateYr As Object
    Dim DateMonth As Object

    Set mai = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strEntryId)
    MsgBox mai.Subject

    If mai.Class = olMail Then
    Set msgNew = objItem
    If (msgNew.Subject Like "Client Media Report*") Then
            DateYr = Format(Now(), "yyyy", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem)
            DateMonth = Format(Now(), "mm. mmmm", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem)

            On Error Resume Next
            MkDir "M:\AutoArchive\Client Media Report\" & DateYr
            On Error GoTo 0
            msgNew.SaveAs "M:\AutoArchive\Client Media Report\" & DateYr & "\" & DateMonth & msgNew.Subject & ".msg"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Just tried this- the email didn't save itself into the folder still. No error messages, and its not saving still.

I tried changing the directory, in case that was at fault, but the same result.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? What error do you get? Which line of code causes the issue?

Comment: Debugging the code doesn't reveal any errors, and it doesn't spit out an errors. It's weird. It literally does nothing when the email arrives.

Comment: Wait. Will this be affected if the emails are arriving in a subfolder, not my inbox folder?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you handle the `NewMailEx` event.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think NewMailEx is triggering at all then. i've enabled macros and given them permission when the pop up appeared, still nothing. Restarted Outlook also. Are there any other steps to installing an Outlook macro besides pasting this code in?

Comment: Have you subscribed to the `NewMailEx` event in the VBA editor?

Comment: Alright, I've got it working for emails that arrive now. It's spitting out the error "Could not open the item" on the line `Set mai = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strEntryId)